Does recognizing the State of Palestine facilitate doing business with it?
Is it easier for the countries that have officially recognized the State of Palestine to do business with it? I don't mean favoritism or political payback for recognition, but purely formal/legal arrangements. E.g., in the context of developing Gaza Marine gas field or importing Palestinian gas, would Spanish companies now have easier time making contracts and getting approval from Palestinian government and the occupation authorities than before the recognition? (Israel presumably still has a say in the matter, as it still controls de facto Palestinian territorial waters.)
